# save as iText.Layout.Element.Image in folder

Tags: c#, itext7

i want to save pdf page as image but no success. i am able to create iText.Layout.Element.Image from pdf with itext7 but stuck here

```
using var pdfreader = new PdfReader("../../../documents/valid.pdf");
PdfDocument origPdf = new PdfDocument(pdfreader);
PdfPage origPage = origPdf.GetPage(1);
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
using var pdfwriter = new PdfWriter(stream);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfwriter);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdf);
Image image = new Image(pageCopy);
// want to save this image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iText 7 `Image` class is (according to JavaDocs) *a layout element that represents an image for inclusion in the document model.* It essentially can wrap arbitrary contents to be added to the contents of some page (or form XObject, ...) in an image like manner. It is **not**, however, an arbitrary-content-to-bitmap converter.

If you want to render a page as a bitmap using iText 7 components, consider using the iText 7 Core add-on [pdfRender](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/convert-pdf-to-image-pdfrender).